# Extracting from text file in R

Tags: r

I need to compare two .txt files with the following formats , with R:

rows in file1:

```
1-11!AIVDM,1,1,,B,11b4N?@P?w<tSF0l4Q@>4?wp1`Oo,0*3D
 1347204643
2-12$GPRMC,153102,A,6300.774,N,05238.627,W,12.9,186,090912,30,W*79
 1347204664
```

( here for some reason the time (1347204643) is in the separate row)

rows in file2:

```
#1:1347204643:11!AIVDM,1,1,,B,11b4N?@P?w<tSF0l4Q@>4?wp1`Oo,0*3D
#2:1347204664:12$GPRMC,153102,A,6300.774,N,05238.627,W,12.9,186,090912,30,W*79
```

I am interested only in verifying if the same ID, which is in the beginning of the row (e.g. 1 and 2 here), exists in both files ( if the ID that exists in file1 exists also in file2).

Can someone help me with this? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: 2-12$GPRMC,153102,A,6300.774,N,05238.627,W,12.9,186,090912,30,W*79 1347204664 is actually the second row in file1...thanks!

Comment: Also, in file2, the rows begin with #

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

First you read 2 two files using `readLines`

```
ll1 <- readLines(textConnection('#1:1347204643:11!AIVDM,1,1,,B,11b4N?@P?w<tSF0l4Q@>4?wp1`Oo,0*3D
#2:1347204664:12$GPRMC,153102,A,6300.774,N,05238.627,W,12.9,186,090912,30,W*79'))
ll2 <- readLines(textConnection('1-11!AIVDM,1,1,,B,11b4N?@P?w<tSF0l4Q@>4?wp1`Oo,0*3D
 1347204643
2-12$GPRMC,153102,A,6300.774,N,05238.627,W,12.9,186,090912,30,W*79
 1347204664'))
```

Do some treatments

```
#Remove '#` fom the first files
ll1 <- gsub('#','',ll1)
#Take only the odd lines from the second file
ll2 <- ll2[c(TRUE,FALSE)]
```

Extract the index of each lines using `substr`

```
ll1 <- substr(ll1,1,1)
ll2 <- substr(ll2,1,1)
```

Now you have this 2 lists :

```
ll1
[1] "1" "2"
> ll2
[1] "1" "2
```

To compare you can use `match`

```
match(ll1,ll2)
[1] 1 2
```

Comment: THank you for the reply.  Since I have actually two files containing large number of rows, I've tried A<-readLines(file.choose()) from file 1.. but then in A is only the first row. How would I get the other rows? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know...Here the standart use `con <- file("test1") ;readLines(con) ;`

Comment: Thanks a lot anyway! I'll keep trying.

Comment: @Mishu Your problem looks a bit strange. what do you get when you try with my second suggestion?

Comment: This is the excerpt of what I get [169] ""                                                                             
[170] ""                                                                             
[171] ""

Comment: [3657] "1586-12$GPRMC,221137,A,6137.185,N,05302.901,W,12.4,188,090912,29,W*7F"                                     
[3658] " 1347228698"                                                                                               
[3659] "1587-12$GPRMC,221159,A,6137.110,N,05302.923,W,12.5,186,090912,29,W*74"                                     
[3660] " 1347228720" ...is what I get when use con<-file(file.choose());readLines(con)..It seems that I lose the ID that I need to compare.. :(